# How do I properly display form HTML input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My code isn't working as I intend it to, and I don't know how to fix it. So, whenever the person types 'hello' in the box, and then presses Submit, the paragraph hat says hi is supposed to display 'good job', but it's not.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="thesearchh" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
<button onclick="submitSearch()">Submit</button>
<p id="searchResult">hi</p>

<script>
function submitSearch() {
if(document.getElementById('thesearchh').includes('hello') == true) {
document.getElementById('searchResult').innerHTML = 'good job';
}

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: an element does not have an `includes` method; a string does. Add `.value` before `.includes`.

Answer (score 0):

you should check input value with `document.getElementById(inputId).value` not with `includes` method. includes method works in arrays and strings but not on DOM elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="thesearchh" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
<button onclick="submitSearch()">Submit</button>
<p id="searchResult">hi</p>

<script>
function submitSearch() {
if(document.getElementById('thesearchh').value === "hello") {
document.getElementById('searchResult').innerHTML = 'good job';
}

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much! I really needed this thx bro

Answer (score 0):

- Stop using inline attributes like: CSS `style` and JS `on*` handlers.  CSS and JS should be in their respective tags or files.
- Use [Element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of the onclick attribute handler
- Use [InputElement.value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#value) to get an :input's (`<textarea>` in your case) value.
- Use `===` to compare it with the desired `"hello"` string
- PS: are you sure you need a `<textarea>` instead of `<input type="text">`?
- Additionally you might want to use String.prototype.trim() to remove whitespaces from your user-input string before comparing. That's up to you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
  #search {
    resize: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="thesearchh"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="thesubmitt">Submit</button>
<p id="searchResult">hi</p>

<script>
// DOM Utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par??document).querySelector(sel);

// Task: Match value "hello":

const elSearch = el("#thesearchh");
const elSubmit = el("#thesubmitt");
const elResult = el("#searchResult");

const submitSearch = () => {
  const userInput = elSearch.value;
  if (userInput === "hello") {
    elResult.textContent = 'good job';
  }
};

elSubmit.addEventListener("click", submitSearch);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added **.value** in your code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <textarea id="thesearchh" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
    <button onclick="submitSearch()">Submit</button>
    <p id="searchResult">hi</p>
    
    <script>
    function submitSearch() {
    if(document.getElementById('thesearchh').value.includes('hello') == true) {
    document.getElementById('searchResult').innerHTML = 'good job';
    }
    
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

here you can see the line iam added .value

```
if(document.getElementById('thesearchh').value.includes('hello') == true){}
```